# how to create pop up in articles in admin joomla2.5

Tags: joomla2.5

I created an article in admin and want to show a pop-up with click event. I tried the following things:

1. Using script tag.But it did not work. And showed value to front side.
2. Used module fancybox and module simple pop-up. But they are showing error. I think because the core jquery file is loaded after the fancybox js file. But I did not know any way to change order of js files in head .

Could any body help me? I am new to joomla . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Got solution.I added fancybox js in templates js and fancybox css in templates.Then $(".modalbox").fancybox();.Then adding div in articles admin

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I added fancybox js in templates js and fancybox css in templates. Then `$(".modalbox").fancybox();`. Then adding div in articles admin.